# MOBILE view map view is not coming correct?

Tags: html, css, mobile, bing-maps

After applying Bootstrap CSS, the mobile view for map which is not in the certain `<div>` it will show out of map div.

Map is not coming accurate.

Our code is,{php}

```
<div id='mapDiv'  style="position:relative;min-height: 478px; min-width:inherit; ">
   <img id="loading" src="./images/loading.gif" />
</div>
```

How to fix the map(bing) in the mobile view correctly?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a PHP issue. Improve your tags to get better answers.

Comment: Well, if you add a `css` and the script is showing wrong, check what's inside the css file. Maybe there is a class conflict or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `id` for your `img` is conflicting with some other `id` in your page and 
you may or may not have inline css or other priority tag for that `id`. So you should review your HTML file.